# How to bind database items in my vaadin combobox

Tags: java, web, vaadin

Good morning every one i enter a job interview and nowadays i have a duty to complete. I need to fill my combobox with inputs in our database in table one column. How can i do that ? Is there any source. I can't find

Comment: What is your technology stack? If you are using JavaEE or Spring, write yourself a repository which fetches the data, inject it in the view, and set the data provider of the combo box to the returned data. If not, provide some of the code you already have.

Comment: @Stephan thanks for helping we use vaadin for framework and hibernate for database our database in postresql but i got it. I use list for getting the values from the database. I am thanksfull for helpin man. Have a nice day.

Comment: Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: vaadin 7 but i find the solution thanks any way